# Infinity loop through array

Tags: jquery

Got a script serving me some urls:

```
["slides\/1.html","slides\/2.html"]
```

Now I want to load those slides for 10 seconds and move forward to next slide. At the end of the Array I want to recall the script to get the new urls again.

My actual solution only shows slide2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   loadPages();
});

function loadPages() {
    $.getJSON("scan.php", function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            console.log(value)
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $('.slides').load('http://axon.info/'+value);
            }, 10000); 
        });
    });
}
```

**Update:**

solved my issue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   loadPages();
});

function loadPages() {
    $.getJSON("scan.php", function(data){
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $('.slides').load('http://axon.info/'+value);
            },(index+1) *8000); 
        });
    });
    setTimeout(loadPages, 1000);
    }
```

anything I could improve?

Answer (score 1):

The loop completes almost instantly so you are actually running multiple `setTimeout` at same time

Use the array `index` as multiplier for the delay

```
   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value)
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('.slides').load('http://axon.info/'+value);
        },(index+1) * 10000); 
    });
```

Comment: This would work for the first loop, but it's not infinite

Comment: thx for the first loop - how to restart the fetch data again?